# Fatal error: index out of range - Swift 3 and Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I have a basic experience in Swift 3 and Firebase and I am building an app for a group of friends in my city that are teachers here at a local school. They want an app for a checklist validation of their students in a way they were connected.

I have an app with a first view controller with a table view and clicking on add student I have a tab bar controller with three more view controllers. At the first one, where the error comes from, I have 2 picker views: 1) student (pckStudents) and 2) teachers (pckTeachers). They come from different nods (childs) from the same main root from Firebase.

```
Main root –
    -- Validation2017
          -- teachers
              -- key
              -- teacherName
          -- students
              -- key
              -- studentName
          -- validation
              -- key
              -- name
              -- final note
              -- dateTime
              ---- Level 1 (...)
```

At this first view controller, where  these two picker view are, I have the declaration for the arrays:

```
var teachers: [teachers] = []
var students: [students] = []
```

I have to create two different arrays, one for students and one for teachers. First, because they are different kind of data, no relationship between them; and second, because all the other ways I have tried I couldn’t resolve an issue trying to load data with only one observe for both items; one snapshot for each child.

Doing this way, the view controllers loads ok, but always when I click to select one of the picker views, I receive the message: fatal error: index out of range. Sometimes when I click and have this error with picker view 1, sometimes number 2. I don’t why this too.

I have tried all descriptions and solutions I have found here and in other sites, but I could not fix it, neither find some specifically for Swift 3 and Xcode 8 and I hope someone could help me. Sorry for my English (I am trying to do my best) and if I have written some term or function or some code action in the wrong way. Thank you for your attention.

My subclass for both arrays: (only switch student... for teacher...)

```
struct students {

var studentName: String?
var key: String!

init(studentName: String, key: String = "") {
    self.studentName = studentName
    self.key = key
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    studentName = snapshotValue["studentName"] as? String
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "studentName": studentName,
        "userKey": key
    ]
}
```

Then, I created two methods - CarregarT() and CarregarS() - for loading each array (place at viewDidLoad): (switch "teaches"and "teacherName" for "students" and "studentName" for CarregarA() )

```
func CarregarT() {
    let refW = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Validation2017").child("teachers")
    refW.queryOrdered(byChild: "teacherName").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        var newTeste2: [teachers] = []
        for resposta in snapshot.children {
            let itemsAadicionar = teachers(snapshot: resposta as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newTeste2.append(itemsAadicionar)
        }
        self.refw2 = newTeste2
        self.pckTeachers.reloadAllComponents()
      })
}
```

And finally, UIPickerView methods for both 1 and 2 (I signed pickerview 1 as tag=1 and pcv2 as tag=2)

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return teachers.count
     }else{
        return students.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
    return teachers[row].teacherName
}else{
return students[row].studentName
     }
```

Thank you.

UPDATED: method didSelectRow

```
var PreceptorG: String!
var NomeG: String!

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let studentCh = students[row].studentName
        let teacherCh = teachers[row].teacherName

            if pickerView.tag == 1{
              PreceptorG = teacherCh

            }else{
                NomeG = studentCh
              }
        }
```

Sorry, I forgot this method before.

Comment: I'm confused which line generates the error. Would you point out to it? Is it coming from here `teachers[row]`?

Comment: Add numberOfComponentsInPickerView and return 1, assuming you have one component? Also, and this is not a technical issue but your student and teacher struct is called teacherArray, you may want to call to studentStruct and teacherStruct for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, sorry @Honey. I had forgotten the didSelectRow. The error message comes indicated for the method. Sorry,  I have updated the code above.

Comment: @Jay, I have done `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` return 1. Just didn't put it here because the text was a little long.

Comment: at the very first line of your `didSelectRow` do `print(students)` likely your array is empty and you're accessing an index which  doesn't exist

Comment: The error at workspace inside didSelectRow. method`Thread 1: EXEC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10082111c) `.

Comment: @Jay Agree. Actually `teacherArray` should be renamed in `Teacher`. No type info in name, capital letter.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `didSelectRow`. Inspect `row`, `students`, `teachers` and `pickerView.tag`.

Comment: @Honey, yes, I can see this now. I have inserted some prints all the lines and I counts the itens when in `numberOfRowsInComponent` and in `titleForRow`, but when arrives didSelectRow they are empty. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Ok, I will try this @shallowThought

Comment: Ok @Jay, I will change both them to clarify

Comment: I guess I fixed it. Now the crashes stope and the arrays are no more empty.

Answer (score 0):

Inside didSelecRow I moved the lines `let studentCh = students[row].studentName` inside its pickerview.tag reference and the same with the other line. And this is the final code for didSelectRow. Now no more crashes:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            if pickerView.tag == 1{
            let teacherCh = teachers[row].teacherName
            PreceptorG = teacherCh

            }else{
            let studentCh = students[row].studentName
            NomeG = studentCh

  }
        }
```